# C# equivalent to PowerShell ConvertFrom-Csv

Tags: c#, powershell, csv

Is there a library in C# that does what the PowerShell command `ConvertFrom-Csv` does?

I am not very familiar with PowerShell and I need to write a C# app that does what a couple PowerShell scripts do, namely transform the data from a CSV file into a different CSV file.

The script uses the command:

```
$data = Get-Content $inFile | Select -Skip 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

This seems to convert the CSV file into a list/array of objects with properties named for the headers of the source CSV file. I can see a way to do this in C#, but it would be pretty involved. I like the simplicity of the PS syntax and would like to do this as simply as possible, but I'm not a much of a C# guru as I need to be either.

So, is there something similar in C#? Is there a way to pull in the powerShell library in C# and call this command from there?

Comment: Take a look at [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx)

Comment: Nothing built-in to c#. You can call vb.net code from c# if you can stop the associated gag reflex .

Comment: [Reading CSV files in C#](//stackoverflow.com/a/1544743)

Comment: I have used TextFieldParser, and it is good, but it does not seem to do what I am describing. At least not from the usages that I see of it. I need to pull in the data from a CSV file, with a header, and have that data placed into an object (list<PSObject> as it were) with fields named for the header.

The powershell ConverFrom-Csv function seems to do this, but what I have seen of TextFieldParser I don't see it doing that.